# Mock an interface instantiation in a function call argument list with phpunit

Tags: php, testing, interface, phpunit

I'm bit new to phpunit .I was trying to cover this function .

```
public function add(AddressInterface $address) : array
{
    $this->data[] = $address;
    return $this->data;
}
```

My test function is as follows

```
public function testAdd()
{
    $collection = new AddressCollection();
    $collection->add($this->createMock(AddressInterface::class));
}
```

and the namespaces are same. But whenever I try running the phpunit , I'm getting this error . 
`TypeError: Argument 1 passed to ValidateAddress\Model\AddressCollection::add() must be an instance of AddressInterface, instance of Mock_AddressInterface_65a1b00b given, called in validateaddress/tests/Model/AddressCollectionTest.php`

Any idea why this is happening? The mocked instance cannot replace the instance of AddressInterface in original add() function version. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you doing `use ValidateAddress\Model\AddressInterface;`?

Comment: Yes of course I'm using it

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you can try to mock too much - if a class that implements `AddressInterface` isn't so complicated, mostly just holding values, it can be perfectly fine to use a real instance - especially since the code you have there is effectively just a setter function.

The test would create a real-enough `Address`, tell the `AddressCollection` to add it to the data, and assert that the returned array contains the same address that it was passed, or at least one more than used to be there.

All that said, I do sometime mock classes, or interfaces into a constructor with PHP7.2, PHPUnit7 and and with the class I'm testing also setting `declare(strict_types=1);` at the top of the file.